# What dependencies do I need for embedded ActiveMQ broker?

Tags: java, maven, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to use embedded ActiveMQ broker for unit testing, as explained here: http://activemq.apache.org/how-to-unit-test-jms-code.html

What Maven dependencies I need to include? At the moment I have just these:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that 
is not native or abstract in class file javax/jms/JMSException
```

When trying to instantiate a broker:

```
final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
```

What else should I add to the list of Maven dependencies? (I'm **not** using Spring)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is simple, just need to remove the `javax:javaee-api` dependency.

Comment: activemq has a transitive dependency on JMS API through activemq-client -> geronimo-jms anyway, best answer.

Answer (score 4):

can you try `activemq-all`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well, maybe there is some other more elegant solution? Actually, the result is the same.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `elegant` :) btw `activemq-all` doesn't really mean including all the AciveMQ jars. It simply means including their `activemq-all-5.5.0.jar` in your build/class path which is the right jar for activemq clients anyway.

Comment: @anubhava, `activemq-all` does mean including all the ActiveMQ JARs. It is a big "uber-JAR" via the Maven Shade Plugin that contains all the classes. It is often a better idea to get the individual JARs containing the components you need.

Answer (score 3):

moved the javaee dependency to the end of the class path. This solved my problem.